# Convert Stream to IntStream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a feeling I'm missing something here. I found myself doing the following

```
private static int getHighestValue(Map<Character, Integer> countMap) {
    return countMap.values().stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).max().getAsInt();
}
```

My problem is with the silly conversion from `Stream` to  `IntStream` via the `mapToInt(Integer::intValue)`

Is there a better way of doing the conversion? all this is to avoid using `max()` from `Stream`, which requires passing a `Comparator` but the question is specifically on the convertion of `Stream` to `IntStream`

Comment: Have you considered using `max(Comparator.<Integer>naturalOrder())`?

Comment: And why exactly do you think it is silly? You want to return an int, so .mapToInt() makes sense...

Comment: @fge because i think i'm wasting a call to autobox the values, which would need O(n) operations. I'm hoping I can get the stream as an IntStream directly

Comment: Well, no, since no values in Collections or Maps can be primitives; and you are not boxing here but unboxing. Still, it's not as expensive as you think. I have a real use case in mind but it's too long to explain in a single comment.

Comment: No, you're not doing any boxing -- the values are already boxed, you're unboxing them (which you have to do to do comparison on them).  You're doing it right.  You're not costing yourself any avoidable computation; if you did it in a plain old loop, you'd still be doing at least as many unbox operations.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Due to type erasure, the `Stream` implementation has no knowledge about the type of its elements and can’t provide you with neither, a simplified `max` operation nor a conversion to `IntStream` method.

In both cases it requires a function, a `Comparator` or a `ToIntFunction`, respectively, to perform the operation using the unknown reference type of the `Stream`’s elements.

The simplest form for the operation you want to perform is

```
return countMap.values().stream().max(Comparator.naturalOrder()).get();
```

given the fact that the *natural order* comparator is implemented as a singleton. So it’s the only comparator which offers the chance of being recognized by the `Stream` implementation *if* there is any optimization regarding `Comparable` elements. If there’s no such optimization, it will still be the variant with the lowest memory footprint due to its singleton nature.

If you insist on doing a conversion of the `Stream` to an `IntStream` there is no way around providing a `ToIntFunction` and there is no predefined singleton for a `Number::intValue` kind of function, so using `Integer::intValue` is already the best choice. You could write `i->i` instead, which is shorter but just hiding the unboxing operation then.

Answer (score 13):

Another way you could do the conversion is with a lambda: `mapToInt(i -> i)`.
Whether you should use a lambda or a method reference is discussed in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24493905/3179759), but the summary is that you should use whichever you find more readable.

Comment: Function.identity()

Comment: @MichalŠtein `Function.identity()` does __not__ work here, because contrary to the lambda `i -> i`, it does not perform unboxing from `Integer` to `int`.

Answer (score 12):

I realize you are trying to avoid a comparator, but you could use the built-in for this by referring to `Integer.compareTo`:

```
private static int getHighestValue(Map<Character, Integer> countMap) {
    return countMap.values().stream().max(Integer::compareTo).get();
}
```

Or as @fge suggests, using `::compare`:

```
private static int getHighestValue(Map<Character, Integer> countMap) {
    return countMap.values().stream().max(Integer::compare).get();
}
```

Comment: Instead of finishing up with `get()` maybe, `orElse(0)` or `orElseThrow(...)` might be "safer"?

Comment: @wassgren Yes, either of those things is great, *especially* if you may have an empty map. Frankly I just used `get()` because I was focused more on the comparator part. Good call.

Comment: I upvoted this although it doesn't answer the actual question since I will use this instead. However, I just want to know what's the best way to convert a Stream to IntStream since I see myself needing this in other cases. BTW, it could be that `stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue)` IS the best way already

Answer (score 2):

If the question is "Can I avoid passing converter while converting from `Stream<T>` to `IntStream`?" one possible answer might be "There is no way in Java to make such conversion type-safe and make it part of the `Stream` interface at the same time".

Indeed method which converts `Stream<T>` to `IntStream` without a converter might be looked like this:

```
public interface Stream<T> {
    // other methods

    default IntStream mapToInt() {
        Stream<Integer> intStream = (Stream<Integer>)this;
        return intStream.mapToInt(Integer::intValue);
    }
}
```

So it suppose to be called on `Stream<Integer>` and will fail on other types of streams. But because streams are lazy evaluated and because of the type erasure (remember that `Stream<T>` is generic) code will fail at the place where stream is consumed which might be far from the `mapToInt()` call. And it will fail in a way that is extremely difficult to locate source of the problem.

Suppose you have code:

```
public class IntStreamTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IntStream intStream = produceIntStream();
        consumeIntStream(intStream);
    }

    private static IntStream produceIntStream() {
        Stream<String> stream = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3").stream();
        return mapToInt(stream);
    }

    public static <T> IntStream mapToInt(Stream<T> stream) {
        Stream<Integer> intStream = (Stream<Integer>)stream;
        return intStream.mapToInt(Integer::intValue);
    }

    private static void consumeIntStream(IntStream intStream) {
        intStream.filter(i -> i >= 2)
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

It will fail on `consumeIntStream()` call with:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$4$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:210)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfInt.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:189)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.IntPipeline.forEach(IntPipeline.java:404)
    at streams.IntStreamTest.consumeIntStream(IntStreamTest.java:25)
    at streams.IntStreamTest.main(IntStreamTest.java:10)
```

Having this stacktrace do you able to quickly identify that the problem is in `produceIntStream()` because `mapToInt()` was called on the stream of the wrong type?

Of course one can write converting method which is type safe because it accepts concrete `Stream<Integer>`:

```
public static IntStream mapToInt(Stream<Integer> stream) {
    return stream.mapToInt(Integer::intValue);
}

// usage
IntStream intStream = mapToInt(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3).stream())
```

but it's not very convenient because it breaks fluent interface nature of the streams.

**BTW:**

Kotlin's extension functions allow to call some code as it is a part of the class' interface. So you are able to call this type-safe method as a `Stream<java.lang.Integer>`'s method:

```
// "adds" mapToInt() to Stream<java.lang.Integer>
fun Stream<java.lang.Integer>.mapToInt(): IntStream {
    return this.mapToInt { it.toInt() }
}

@Test
fun test() {
    Arrays.asList<java.lang.Integer>(java.lang.Integer(1), java.lang.Integer(2))
            .stream()
            .mapToInt()
            .forEach { println(it) }
}
```