# Convert generic arraylist to non-generic using Java 8 Stream

Tags: java, arraylist, java-stream

I have some old code I'm trying to streamline:

```
ArrayList arr = (generic arraylist)
int[] newArr = new int[arr.size()];
for(int i=0; i<arr.size(); i++){
    newArr[i]=(int)arr.get(i);
}
```

I want to use the Java Stream API to simplify this. Here is my attempt:

```
ArrayList arr = (generic arraylist)
List<Integer> = arr.stream().map(m -> (int)m).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

My understanding is that it would iterate through arr, typecast every object m to an int, and then collect it into a List. But my compiler says that the right-hand-side of the second line returns and Object and not a List. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `int` is premitive and `ArrayList` can only hold objects like `Integer`, what are you trying to do ? and why do you need type casting ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Stream to IntStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28015278/convert-stream-to-intstream)

Comment: Using the word “generic” is confusing here. Do you mean [Generics](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java)? If not, change your wording. Give a complete code example.

Comment: FYI: [*How do I get an IntStream from a List<Integer>?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24633913/642706)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per your attempt, it looks like you want to map your `ArrayList` to an `ArrayList<Integer>`. The good news is, you don't need to do any of this. The runtime type of `ArrayList<Integer>` is just `ArrayList` (this is called *type erasure* if you want to search for information about it). Only the compiler knows about the parameterized type.

So this code does what you want:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Cast {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //  This represents the ArrayList of Integer in your existing code
        ArrayList raw = new ArrayList(java.util.Arrays.asList(
            Integer.valueOf(1), Integer.valueOf(2), Integer.valueOf(3)
        ));

        //  You know what it is, so all you need to do is cast
        ArrayList<Integer> typed = (ArrayList<Integer>)raw;
        
        //  Still works; now recognized as list of integer
        for (Integer x : typed) {
            System.err.println(x);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: “raw” is the technical term here, not “untyped”. `ArrayList` is itself a type. See [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html).

Comment: Thank you! This was a more elegant/simple way of solving the problem :)

Comment: Cool, @BasilBourque, I've changed the variable name to reflect the terminology.

Comment: And your variable name in `typed =` should be something like `parameterizedTyping =` or `castWithGenerics =`.

Comment: You should not use `Integer` constructors, since they are deprecated.

Comment: Removed the Integer constructors