# Lambda expression vs method reference implementation details

Tags: java, lambda

Given this:

```
class MyClass {
    static class A {
        public boolean property() {
            return Math.random() < 0.5;
        }
    }

    static List<A> filterLambda(List<A> list) {
        return list.stream().filter(a -> a.property()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    static List<A> filterMethodCall(List<A> list) {
        return list.stream().filter(A::property).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

- What are the differences in **what the compiler does** for each method?
- In case there's any, is there a difference in memory usage or runtime? (even if it's small, the question is just academic)

PD: I know the question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24487805/lambda-expression-vs-method-reference) but I think it's not been addressed correctly.

Comment: "What the compiler does" is probably beyond the scope of an answer here. The spec gives some theoretical background information, but it's not clear how deeply you want to dive into the actual compiler *implementation*. All I can say for sure is that **the bytecode that is generated for both methods will be identical**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an extract from the [Brian Goetz's doc](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-translation.html) linked by Brett Oken:

> **When the compiler encounters a lambda expression, it first lowers
>   (desugars) the lambda body into a method** whose argument list and
>   return type match that of the lambda expression, possibly with some
>   additional arguments (for values captured from the lexical scope, if
>   any.) At the point at which the lambda expression would be captured,
>   it generates an invokedynamic call site, which, when invoked, returns
>   an instance of the functional interface to which the lambda is being
>   converted. This call site is called the lambda factory for a given
>   lambda. The dynamic arguments to the lambda factory are the values
>   captured from the lexical scope. The bootstrap method of the lambda
>   factory is a standardized method in the Java language runtime library,
>   called the lambda metafactory. The static bootstrap arguments capture
>   information known about the lambda at compile time (the functional
>   interface to which it will be converted, a method handle for the
>   desugared lambda body, information about whether the SAM type is
>   serializable, etc.)
>
> **Method references are treated the same way as lambda expressions,
>   except that most method references do not need to be desugared into a
>   new method**; we can simply load a constant method handle for the
>   referenced method and pass that to the metafactory.

Examples extracted from same doc:

As an example, consider a lambda that captures a field minSize:

```
list.filter(e -> e.getSize() < minSize )
```

We desugar this as an instance method, and pass the receiver as the first captured argument:

```
list.forEach(INDY((MH(metaFactory), MH(invokeVirtual Predicate.apply),
                    MH(invokeVirtual B.lambda$1))( this ))));

private boolean lambda$1(Element e) {
    return e.getSize() < minSize; }
```

While

```
list.filter(String::isEmpty)
```

is translated as:

```
list.filter(indy(MH(metaFactory), MH(invokeVirtual Predicate.apply),
             MH(invokeVirtual String.isEmpty))()))
```

Answer (score 3):

One case where we can find the difference lambda expression & method reference is using as part of Supplier interface. Lets say we have below static method

```
public static <T, E> T catchException(Supplier<T> resolver) {
    try {
        T result = resolver.get();
        return  result ;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception");
        return null;
    }
}
```

When we call the method using lambda expression as below, code work fine since the lambda expression passed as part of Supplier & executed only when get() method is called where the exception is caught.

```
List<String> underlyers=null;
System.out.println(catchException(()->underlyers.size()));
```

When we call the method using method reference as below, we get NullPointerExecption before calling the method since the reference is executed before passing in to the supplier. The control does not reach get() method in this case.

```
List<String> underlyers=null;
System.out.println(catchException(underlyers::size));
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13) is the java language spec on method references.

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27) is the spec for lambda expressions.

Lambdas are quite a bit more complex from a rules perspective.

In both cases, however, the result is an invokedynamic call.

Brian Goetz has written a [doc](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-translation.html) on how this works.

Comment: I'm not asking which one should be used, but thanks for the links