# Is this correct usage of lambdas in Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8

```
final List<String> userIds = request.getUserIds();
final List<String> keys = userIds.stream().map(p -> { 
    return removePrefix(p); 
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Basically, every key in the list of `userIds` contains a prefix "_user" which I want to remove for every key. So, I am invoking the `removePrefix` function on each item of the list and storing that result in another list called "keys"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it's fine although you could make it a little shorter and more readable with a method reference and a static import:

```
final List<String> keys = userIds.stream()
                                 .map(this::removePrefix)
                                 .collect(toList());
```

Comment: Is there any difference between `.map(p -> removePrefix(p))` and `.map(this::removePrefix)`. Yeah, the first one is longer with 2 characters, but anything else?

Comment: No functional difference - but I find method references more readable. It's obviously a matter of taste...

Comment: @NagyVilmos That can easily be verified... And here is more on the subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24487805/lambda-expression-vs-method-reference

Comment: @Nagy Vilmos: no, they are slightly different. A method reference does not need a synthetic method to hold the lambda’s code but refers to the target method directly. Well, in most cases; sometimes it requires a helper method which is exactly like the lambda expression, e.g. for varargs methods or array constructors.

Answer (score 4):

The answer of @assylias is nice, but if you are not worried about modifying the list in place (and that you are allowed to modify it via its `ListIterator#set` method), a good alternative could be to use `replaceAll`:

```
final List<String> userIds = request.getUserIds();
userIds.replaceAll(this::removePrefix);
```

`replaceAll` works here because your function is a function from T to T (where T is `String` in your case), so basically a `UnaryOperator`, which is a `Function<T,T>`.

If the mapping you wanted to apply would have been from a type T to U, then getting the list's stream and doing the mapping via the `Stream#map` method (like you did) is the standard idiom.