# How to convert from ArrayList<Double> to double[]

Tags: java, arraylist

Does anyone know how to pass a double arraylist into another method? (I have highlighted it)I get this message from compiler : **cannot convert from ArrayList to double[]**

```
                ArrayList<Double> value  = new ArrayList<Double>();
                while (rs.next()) 
                {  
                    ArrayList<Integer> r=new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
                    r.add(rs.getInt("Type"));
                    r.add(rs.getInt("Budget"));
                    r.add(rs.getInt("Day"));
                    r.add(rs.getInt("Preferences"));
                    int vec2[] = r.stream().mapToInt(t -> t).toArray();
                    double cos_sim=cosine_similarity(vec1,vec2);
                    value.add(cos_sim);
                }

                pick_highest_value_here_and_display(value);
                ps.close();
                rs.close();
                conn.close();


            }


    private void pick_highest_value_here_and_display(ArrayList<Double> value) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            **double aa[]=value ;**
            double highest=aa[0];
            for(int i=0;i<aa.length;i++)
            {
                if(aa[i]>highest){
                    highest=aa[i];
                }

            }

            System.out.println(highest);
        }
```

Comment: @Jashaszun does double method same with int?

Comment: Apart of the fact that is possible duplicate as already stated from someone why exactly you want to make it array? You can get elements of ArrayList by index too also to modify them by index too.

Comment: Your `pick_highest_value_here_and_display` method could simply be `double maxValue = Collections.max(...);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Java8` in a same way you used it for `int[]`

```
ArrayList<Double> value  = new ArrayList<Double>();
double[] arr = value.stream().mapToDouble(v -> v.doubleValue()).toArray();
```

**OR** (As per below comment of [`yshavit`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1076640/yshavit))

```
double[] arr = value.stream().mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).toArray();
```

Comment: Thanks ! That's what I'm looking for :)

Comment: Just as an FYI, `v -> v.doubleValue` can also be done as `Double::doubleValue` (but it's purely stylistic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24487805/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23688547/1011791

Comment: Dear DownVoter please explain your downvote.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy all the element to a `double[]` by copying one at a time, but you don't need to.

```
List<Double> value = Arrays.asList(1.1, 3.3, 2.2);

Optional<Double> max = value.stream().max(Comparator.<Double>naturalOrder());
System.out.println(max.get());
```

prints

```
3.3
```

Comment: This is useful. I never noticed the `max` method, and have been using `reduce` so far for such computations.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change to `Double[]` then you can do like :-

```
Double[] doubleArr=  value.toArray(new Double[value.size()]);
```

Else if you want `double[]`, then you can do like :-

```
double[] doubleArr= new double[value.size()];
    int index = 0;
    for(double i : value){
        doubleArr[index] = i; // unboxing is automtically done here
        index++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution:

```
        ArrayList<Double> a = new ArrayList<Double>();
        a.add(0.23);
        a.add(2.4);
        Double[] b = new Double[a.size()];
        b = a.toArray(b);
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(b[i]);
        }
```