# SONAR: Replace this lambda with a method reference

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, sonarqube, method-reference

Sonar tells me "Replace this lambda with a method reference"

```
public class MyClass {

    private List<SomeValue> createSomeValues(List<Anything> anyList) {
        return anyList //
               .stream() //
               .map(anything -> createSomeValue(anything)) //
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
   }

    private SomeValue createSomeValue(Anything anything) {
        StatusId statusId = statusId.fromId(anything.getStatus().getStatusId());
        return new SomeValue(anything.getExternId(), statusId);
    }

}
```

Is this possible here? I tried several things, like

```
.map(MyClass::createSomeValue) //
```

but I need to change the method to static then. And I am not a big fan of static methods.

Explanation of SonarQube is:

> Method/constructor references are more compact and readable than using lambdas, and are therefore preferred.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, you can use `this::createSomeValue`:

```
private List<SomeValue> createSomeValues(List<Anything> anyList) {
    return anyList //
            .stream() //
            .map(this::createSomeValue) //
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

This kind of [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) is called ["Reference to an instance method of a particular object"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html#object). In this case, you are referring to the method `createSomeValue` of the instance `this`.

---

Whether it is "better" or not that using a lambda expression is a matter of opinion. However, you can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24493905/1743880) written by [Brian Goetz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3553087/brian-goetz) that explains why method-references were added in the language in the first place.