# Variable passed from Method.invoke doesn't show up in anything but System.out.println

Tags: java, methods, invoke

What I'm trying to do is create in input box for a game I'm making that displays on-screen with a message such as

> "Name: (input would appear here)"

What I did was pass in the message, which object I want my input to go to, and what function will use the variable(such as a function that sets the input to the player's name). Now, I could just access the input variable from the InputBox object, but, in the long run, this will be more efficient. I'm using `Method.invoke` to pass the function into the object I want with the input string as an argument. Here is my code:

```
public class InputBox extends Textbox {

    public String input = "";
    private String out;
    private Object obj;

    private int lastLastKey = 0;

    /** 
     * 
     * @param message
     * @param cl The object/class where the output variable is.
     * @param out The method to run. Only takes the input variable, so use this format: void toRun(String input)
     */
    public InputBox(String message, Object obj, String out) {
        super(message);
        this.out = out;
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    public void tick(Game game){                
        if (game.input.lastKey != 0 && !game.input.keys[KeyEvent.VK_ENTER]
                && !game.input.keys[KeyEvent.VK_SPACE] && !game.input.keys[KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT] && !game.input.keys[KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SLASH]){
            if(game.input.lastKey != lastLastKey) input+=Character.toUpperCase((char) game.input.lastKey);
        }else if(game.input.keys[KeyEvent.VK_ENTER] && !input.isEmpty() && !cleared){
            Method method = null;
            try {
                method = obj.getClass().getMethod(out, new Class[]{ String.class, Object.class });
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                method.invoke(obj, new Object[]{ input, obj });
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            cleared = true;
        }

        lastLastKey = game.input.lastKey;
    }

    public void render(Graphics g){
        if(!cleared){
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.fillRect(10, Display.height-110, Display.width-20, 100);

            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawRect(10, Display.height-110, Display.width-20, 100);

            g.setFont(Game.smallFont);
            FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
            g.drawString(message+" "+input, Display.width/2-fm.stringWidth(message+" "+input)/2, Display.height-50);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is that whenever I run this code, the variable is passed to the other class like I want, but the only thing I can do to it is use System.out.print on it. Other variables work, but this doesnt

Comment: I don't understand what that means. Can you please rephrase, ideally adding a [mcve] showing the issue with `System.out.print`?

Comment: When I pass the variable input to another class using Method.invoke, the variable is received correctly. I did a System.out.println(input) and it came up with RYAN, which was what I typed in. But when I try to display it on the actual screen, it doesn't come up, but if I use another variable, it does. I also tried writing it to a file; that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your description for the constructor says that the expected method has a signature of

```
void toRun(String input) {}
```

But your reflection code looks for a method with the signature

```
void toRun(String input, Object o) {}
```

---

If you are using Java 8 you can make use of a [Consumer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html) and remove all the reflection code:

```
public class InputBox extends Textbox {

    private Consumer<String> out;

    public InputBox(String message, Consumer<String> out) {
        this.out = out;
        ...
    }

    public void tick(Game game){
        ...
        out.apply(input);
        ...
    }
}
```

Assuming that your `Player` class has a method `setName(String)` like this:

```
public class Player {
    public void setName(String name) {
    }
}
```

you can create an `InputBox` with a method reference

```
public InputBox createNameInputBox(Player p) {
    return new InputBox("Name: ", p::setName);
}
```

or with a lambda expression

```
public InputBox createAlternateNameInputBox(Player p) {
    return new InputBox("Name: ", name -> p.setName(name));
}
```

To read more about lambda expressions and method references see the Java Tutorial series (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html). For a discussion of whether you should use method references or lambda expressions see https://stackoverflow.com/a/24493905/5646962

Comment: How do I initialize a consumer object?

Comment: @bloobchube added example code and links for reference

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Now I can finally continue developing my game.