# Java Method reference not expected here

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, comparator, method-reference

How exactly do you chain method references for instances with Java 8? Example:

```
Collections.sort(civs,Comparator.comparing(Civilization::getStrategy.getStrategLevel));
```

`getStrategy` of a `Civilization` instance returns a `Strategy` object instance which has the instance method `getStrategyLevel`.

Why doesn't the `Comparator.comparing` method return a comparator with it's functional interface implemented by the lambda expression?

Comment: Just use a lambda.

Comment: A method reference is a _reference to a method_.  The chain "call `getStrategy()`, then call `getStrategyLevel()` on the result) is not a method, therefore it is not suitable for describing with a method reference.  If you want to describe an arbitrary bag of imperative code, use a lambda; method refs are a (hopefully more readable) shorthand provided for the special case where the lambda body is a single method whose argument list matches exactly that of the target functional interface.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24487805/lambda-expression-vs-method-reference/24493905#24493905

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In that case, you should use a lambda, you can't apply a method reference directly:

```
Collections.sort(civs, Collectors.comparing(c -> c.getStrategy().getStrategLevel()));
```

Though, there is a way to use a method reference here. Assuming that you have a class like

```
class CivilizationUtils {
    public static Integer getKeyExtractor(Civilization c) {
        return c.getStrategy().getStrategLevel();
    }
}
```

the issue could be solved like

```
Collections.sort(civs, Collectors.comparing(CivilizationUtils::getKeyExtractor));
```

Comment: getStrategy is not a static method

Comment: how would I provide a method reference to the instance method `getStrategyLevel` through an instance of `Strategy` which is accessed through an instance of `Civilization`. Should I just use a regular lambda expression for the comparator?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do it with a method reference, you need to use a lambda expression or create a static method.

**There are four kinds of method references:**

1. Reference to a **static method** like `ContainingClass::staticMethodName`
2. Reference to **an instance method of a particular object** like `containingObject::instanceMethodName`
3. Reference to **an instance method of an arbitrary object of a particular type** like `ContainingType::methodName`
4. Reference to **a constructor** like `ClassName::new`

More details about [`method reference`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).

So here, with a `lambda expression` it would be:

```
Collections.sort(civs, Comparator.comparing(c -> c.getStrategy.getStrategLevel()));
```

Or in case you create a static method

```
public static int getStrategLevel(Civilization c) {
    return c.getStrategy().getStrategLevel();
}
```

Then your code would be:

```
Collections.sort(civs, Comparator.comparing(MyClass::getStrategLevel));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Collections.sort(civs,Comparator.comparing(civ -> civ.getStrategy().getStrategLevel()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Different example, but I have a method

```
void m(Predicate<String> stringPredicate)
```

and a utility class

```
class Utilities {
  static boolean condition1(String s) { ... }
  static boolean condition2(String s) { ... }
  ...
}
```

and I wanted to invoke m with a predicate that returns true iff Utilities.condition1 returns false. The Java grammar allows me to write

```
m(Utilities::condition1)
```

but not

```
m(Utilities::condition1.negate())
```

(an unfortunate violation of [referential transparency](https://www.sitepoint.com/what-is-referential-transparency/)), and the compiler complained, "Java Method reference not expected here."

My workaround was to write a method

```
Predicate<String> not(Predicate<String> p) {
  return p;
}
```

and then to write the call

```
m(not(Utilities::condition1))
```

--which is allowed by the Java grammar.