# Is Java 8 instance method reference an equivalent to lambda call? In my case it is NOT

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, lambda, method-reference

I observe a very strange behavior of method reference. We have a web app and chain of servlet hierarchy: Servlet A extends Servlet B extends `HttpServlet` (let's overlooked why do we need this).

The web app is hosting under Tomcat/Java 8 (web.xml version="3.1" metadata-complete="true").
At my local laptop (Tomcat 8.0.35 or 8.5.15, Java 8 Update 131, OSX) I observe stack overflow for such servlet code:

```
public class A extends B {
    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest pRequest, HttpServletResponse pResponse) throws ServletException, IOException {
        ServletCommon.servletServiceWrapper(pRequest, pResponse, super::service);
    }
}
```

The stack overflow (see below) looks very suspicious - **it doesn't contain class B** in the hierarchy at all! **Class A calls `HttpServlet`** directly (Why!? And how this even possible!!!????).

At the same time code with lambda works fine:

```
public class A extends B {
    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest pRequest, HttpServletResponse pResponse) throws ServletException, IOException {
        ServletCommon.servletServiceWrapper(pRequest, pResponse, (t, u) -> super.service(t, u));
    }
}
```

The wrapper also contains very simple code:

```
public class ServletCommon {
    @FunctionalInterface
    public interface MyBiConsumer<T, U>{
        void accept(T t, U u) throws ServletException, IOException ;
    }
public static void servletServiceWrapper(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        MyBiConsumer<HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse> pDelegate) throws ServletException, IOException {
        pDelegate.accept(request, response);
    }
}
```

Stack trace

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    ServletA.lambda$service$0(ServletA.java:19)
    ServletCommon.servletServiceWrapper(ServletCommon.java:31)
    ServletA.service(ServletA.java:19)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    ServletA.lambda$service$0(ServletA.java:19)
    ServletCommon.servletServiceWrapper(ServletCommon.java:31)
    ServletA.service(ServletA.java:19)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    ...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you construct a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?  I can't repro this behaviour: http://ideone.com/khkDCK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pretty much, yeah](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24487805/lambda-expression-vs-method-reference).

You're managing to call the wrong `service()` method (the public one with `ServletRequest`, not the protected one with `HttpServletRequest`), resulting in an infinite loop. However your example code isn't clear enough to indicate why that's happening.

Comment: You're right, but why "super::service" point out to HttpServlet.service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res), but "(t, u) -> super.service(t, u)" point out to "B.service(HttpServletRequest pRequest, HttpServletResponse pResponse)". I observer that the behavior is differ from runtime env. (i.e. Eclipse, Tomcat, Jetty etc.)

Comment: Could you try working out the simplest possible test case and see if the behaviour is really different between environments? That could warrant a bug report, if the method resolution works in a non-deterministic fashion.

Comment: Sounds like a compiler bug. I couldn’t find any `javac` version having that bug, so perhaps, there’s an `ecj` version having such a bug…

Comment: As I mentioned in the post, the bug is under Tomcat (compiled by javac) and I didn't observe it under Eclipse + Jetty.