# Replace lambda expression with method Reference

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I want to replace my lambda expression with a method reference. Following is my code snippet.

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface MessageProcessor<T, E extends Exception> {
    void process(T t) throws E;
}
```

and my class is

```
public class MessageHandler {
    public static Map<String, MessageProcessor<JsonElement, Exception>> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("create_key" , (jsonElement) -> MessageUtil.processCreate(jsonElement));
    map.put("update_key" , (jsonElement) -> MessageUtil.processUpdate(jsonElement));
    map.put("delete_key" , (jsonElement) -> MessageUtil.processDelete(jsonElement));
}
```

and my utility methods are

```
public static void processCreate(JsonElement jsonElement) throws Exception {
     // create logic
}

public static void processUpdate(JsonElement jsonElement) throws Exception {
     // update logic
}
public static void processDelete(JsonElement jsonElement) throws Exception {
    // delete logic
}
```

Now I want to replace the lambda expression with a method reference. How can I replace?

Comment: `map.put("create_key" , MessageUtil::processCreate);`?

Comment: Why?  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24493905/1552534)

Comment: Or just let your IDE do the conversion.

Comment: @WJS Method references are commonly agreed to be, most of the time, more compact and readable than using lambdas, and are therefore preferred.

Comment: I disagree (did you see the question I cited?) With your method reference I have no idea what it takes as an argument. With the lambda, I know it takes a JSON element.  As long as the parameters are properly named, lambda's aid the documentation process.  But I also use method references quite a bit.  Especially in streams where the arguments to the references are better understood or obvious.  They should be used when it makes sense to do so.   In your case, I would use lambdas.