# Two objects supplier

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I have a binary function:

```java
public Integer binaryFunction(Integer a, Integer b){
    //some stuff
}
```

And I have this stream:

```java
Integer fixedValue = ...
List<Integer> otherValues = ...
otherValues.map(value -> binaryFunction(value, fixedValue)).collect(...);
```

I would like to know how can I use `map(this::binaryFunction)` in my stream. I tried something like this but it won't work:

```java
values.map(value -> (value, fixedValue)).map(this::binaryFunction).collect(...);
```

But it does not work. I'm looking for a supplier that can take two values.

Note: I don't want to change `binaryFunction` declaration.

Comment: If it takes two values, it isn't a `supplier`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do this.  You must use the lambda you have shown.

You could write a function that modifies binary functions to fix their first argument, but its body is just going to be the same lambda.

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can do this if you have fixedValue as a class level variable and you dont need to supply it in the function. In other words

```
public class Foo {
    private Integer fixedValue;


    public Integer binaryFunction(Integer a) {
        //use fixedValue (as it is class variable)
        //some stuff
    }

    public void doSomeThing() {
        this.fixedValue = ...//setting fixed value here
        List<Integer> otherValues = ...
        otherValues.map(this::binaryFunction)...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this.

```
Integer fixedValue = 8;

 List<Integer> otherValues = List.of(10, 20, 30, 40);
 Function<Integer, Integer> fnc = k -> binaryFunction(
         k, fixedValue);
 List<Integer> list = otherValues.stream().map(fnc).toList();
 System.out.println(list);
```

prints

```
[18, 28, 38, 48]
```

```
public Integer binaryFunction(Integer a, Integer b) {
     return a + b;
}
```

But I would opt for what you had originally considered which does the same thing.

```
List<Integer> list = otherValues.stream()
            .map(val->binaryFunction(fixedValue, val)).toList();
```

There is nothing gained by using a method reference over a lambda. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24493905/1552534_) answer by Brian Goetz.